# jQuery - Get value of the next option in a dropdown after the selected one based on attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select

HTML Output

```
<option task_estimated_hours="100" value="1"> - Parent Task</option>
<option task_estimated_hours="50" value="2"> -  - Child task</option>
<option task_estimated_hours="50" value="3"> -  - Child task</option>
```

jQuery Code:

```
$('#dropDownId option:selected').next().val()
```

The above will obviously give me `value` of next option after selected one but not on basis of attrbitue which is `task_estimated_hours`. The below do not seem to be working. It says `TypeError: $(...).attr(...).next is not a function`

```
$('#dropDownId option:selected').attr('task_estimated_hours').next().val();
```

How can I fetch value of next option based on attrbitue passed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This :-

```
$('#dropDownId option:selected').next().attr('task_estimated_hours');
```

**Side Note :-** Use HTML5 custom `data-*` attributes i.e instead of `task_estimated_hours` use `data-task_estimated_hours`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2hwm0yjf/3/)

Comment: The option would then be `<option data-task-hours="100" value="1"> - Parent Task</option>` and to fetch it can we use `$('#dropDownId option:selected').next().attr('data-task-hours');` ?

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy..no a better way is to use `.data()` refer [this](http://jsfiddle.net/0z2oebe6/)

Comment: Even if we are not using `.val()`, it gives out the value. How come `.next().data('task-hours')` fetches value ?

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy..you are mistaken .. its not giving value it is giving attribute `task-hours` value as shown in above fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

May be this may help you

**HTML:**

```
<select id="dropDownId">
<option task_estimated_hours="10" value="1">1 option</option>
<option task_estimated_hours="20" value="2" selected="selected">2 option</option> 
<option value="3" >3 option</option>
<option task_estimated_hours="40" value="4">4 option</option>
</select>
```

**jQuery:**

```
alert($('#dropDownId option:selected').nextAll("option[task_estimated_hours]:first").attr("task_estimated_hours"));
```

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tushar490/fh4v2ebe/):

```
$('select option:selected').next('option[task_estimated_hours]').val();
```